# How do I add extra plists in xCode in the Settings.bundle for use with the InAppSettingsKit iPhone library?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch, inappsettingskit

This is probably a really silly question. but I'm struggling with it :(

I am trying to add a Root.inApp.plist file to my project so that i can have inapp specific settings for my iPhone app.

I have integrated InAppSettingsKit fine, its currently only working with the one Root.plist file tho.
I would like to add a Root.inApp.plist file to my project so that i can have inapp specific settings.

When i try to add another property file in Xcode it doesn't seem to sit under the Settings.bundle, how do i get it to show up in my Settings.bundle structure like this?:

[image: I want other plists to show up under my Settings.bundle]

I have tried to import the inappsettingskit bundle file also without luck :( my project doesn't recognise the Settings.bundle for some reason

Please help

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No way to do that in Xcode, I believe. Just reveal the Settings bundle in Finder and add the new file to it. It'll automatically show up in Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate your existing plist file, then right click any property and select iPhone Settings plist under Property List Type.